# How do validators work on the client side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a simple validator. It works fine with server side requests but it does not work on the client side because of the forbidden post back. .Net's `RequiredAttribute` validator works on the client side and does not need a post back.

How can I change my validator to work like it?

My validator gets a string and checks if it is at least 5 characters long.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | 
  AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _length = 0;

    public MyValidatorAttribute(int length)
    {
        _length = length;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
                                         ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string data = (string)value;
            if (data.Length < _length)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("length is short");
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}

public class MyValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<MyValidatorAttribute>
{
    int minlength = 5;
    string errorMsg = string.Empty;

    public MyValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, 
                       ControllerContext context, 
                       MyValidatorAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        errorMsg = attribute.ErrorMessage;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> 
                                GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule validationRule = 
                                  new ModelClientValidationRule();

        validationRule.ErrorMessage = errorMsg;
        validationRule.ValidationType = "MyValidator";

        validationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("minlength", minlength);

        return new[] { validationRule };

    }
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty to rephrase your question. Please check if this is what you actually meant. It wasn't always clear.

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://johnmj.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/unobtrusive-custom-validator-for-mvc3/